# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, label, version

Good day,

Hitting unsupported pseudo when upgrade jQuery to v1.12.4.

Here is my jsp code:

```
<label name="role.label">maker</label>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$(':label[name="role.label"]').show();
```

All these are working fine before I upgrade my jQuery. After I upgrade it, I am hitting `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: label`.

Found that the solution is :

```
$('[name="role.label"]').show();
```

By remove the `:label` in front.

However, I have thousand of similar jQuery function, any other solution on this? Or this is the only solution?

Addition, there are some place that do not need to change, for example `input`:

```
$(':input[name="bankUserProfile.userGroup.role.name"]').val(data);
```

This one work either in old jQuery and v1.12.4.

Comment: Never seen that selector `:label`, are you sure it wasn't a custom extension? Can't really see why it would be of benefit over the tagname `label` either. `:input` however also includes `<select>` and `<textarea>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest just using the tagname for `<label>` and if there are attributes in selector keep those also

```
$('label[name="role.label"]').show();
```

beyond that you don't seem to have any other issues and can follow the documented pseudo selectors in the [selectors api](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Note that `:label` is not documented

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. Based on research, I went and remove label tag.